# "such that", "so that" or "in a way that" in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I wrote:

> The problem is that "can we cover the bigger rectangle with small rectangles **such that** no two rectangles overlap and no gap opens up"

Is it a correct usage of *such that*? Could I use "so that"? How about "in a way that"?

Is *open ups* the correct verb choice for *gap* here?

Comment: Another issue: With *The problem is that* the clausal complement of **that** must be a declarative; it cannot be a question. You would need to say *The problem is, can we ....?*  **such that** is fine and idiomatic in this context, or **so that**.

Comment: Yes -  ***such that, so that,*** and ***in a way that*** (and ***in such a way that***) are all perfectly good alternatives for your context. Or just plain ***so*** without ***that***. It's just a stylistic choice, where it's a bit pointless to suggest any particular versions are "better" or "worse" than any others. Note that it's ***opens up*** (***open ups*** is garbage English).

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you, you mean *... so without two rectangles overlap or a gap opens up*?

Comment: Certainly not! You can't just arbitrarily change ***no*** in the original to ***without*** in your rephrasing. The problem is *Can we cover the bigger rectangle with small rectangles **so** no two rectangles overlap and no gap opens up?* Note the punctuation (required because the "problem" is framed as a *question*).

Comment: @fumber thanks, LOL, I thought you meant *so without* is another alternative. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

***Such that*** is a natural and appropriate term to use here. *So that* is also acceptable, and less formal. *In a way that* is not grammatical, though *in such a way that* is - and is essentially what *such that* means. You could also use *in a way that means*, though that comes across as much more informal.

"No gap opens up" will be understood, but is not idiomatic, and some might argue as to whether it is semantically correct. "**There are no gaps**" would be more natural.

You also need to lose the *that* in "The problem is that". That quotation marks have you covered. If you didn't have the quotation marks, you'd want something like "the problem is **to figure out if we can** cover the bigger rectangle..."